# JNA loading many libraries with same method name

Tags: java, jna

I have some problems when I use JNA to call different .so in my program.
It seems that my native shared libraries can't declare a method with the same name.

Example :
I have a native1.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int anotherMethod() {
    return 100;
}
int method() {
     return 1 + anotherMethod();
}
```

And a native2.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int anotherMethod() {
    return 200;
}
int method() {
    return 2 + anotherMethod();
}
```

Each are compiled in a shared library (libnative1.so and libnative2.so).

```
$ gcc -m64 -shared -fPIC -o linux-x86-64/libnative1.so native1.c
$ gcc -m64 -shared -fPIC -o linux-x86-64/libnative2.so native2.c
```

(I am on a 64bit linux)

So invoking method() should return :

- 101 in native1
- 202 in native2

I will try it in a small Java Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Native1 native1 = (Native1) Native.loadLibrary("native1", Native1.class);
    Native2 native2 = (Native2) Native.loadLibrary("native2", Native2.class);
    System.out.println(native1.method());
    System.out.println(native2.method());
}
```

The libraries interfaces are minimalists:

```
public interface Native1 extends Library {
    int method();
}
```

And

```
public interface Native2 extends Library {
    int method();
}
```

I obtain :

> 101 // OK
>
> 102 // Should be 202 !

It means the good method() invoked, but when my native code calls anotherMethod(), only the one from native1 is invoked.

I think Native.loadLibrary() loads my shared libraries and flatten it so only the first "anotherMethod" symbol exists.

In my real world case, the C code isn't under my responsibility, it is provided by another editor, so the less I have to edit it is the best

Is there a way to easily separate each shared library, like in a namespace or maybe a gcc option I missed out ?

Comment: Does it work if you do the same thing using C?  You can also load the libraries with different symbol scopes; by default they are loaded with `RTLD_GLOBAL`.  You may have better luck with `RTLD_LOCAL` (see the man page for dlopen).

Comment: With a main using dlopen, I can call the methods without any errors (101 and 202 are printed).
But RTLD_GLOBAL option produce the same error (101 and 102).
Do you think there is a way to simulate RTLD_LOCAL in JNA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling [`Native.loadLibrary()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-), you can supply a `Map` of options including the key `Library.OPTION_OPEN_FLAGS` with a value corresponding to `RTLD_LOCAL`.  That should fix your issue.

```
Map options = new HashMap();
int RTLD_LOCAL = 0x4; // or whatever value it has on your platform
options.put(Library.OPTION_OPEN_FLAGS, RTLD_LOCAL);
Mylib lib = Native.loadLibrary("mylib", Mylib.class, options);
```

You can look up the value of `RTLD_LOCAL` with `grep RTLD_LOCAL /usr/include/*.h` on your target system.

Comment: Yes it is the good option. Thank you. On my system I have to use the value 1 (RTLD_LAZY + RTLD_LOCAL) and it seems good